# How to exclude a site which comes under a specific domain in a cookie c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, cookies, subdomain

We have a `set cookie` for a `domain` as `.example.com` and we have below `sites` which comes under this `domain`.

`login.example.com`

`articles.example.com`

`fitness.example.com`

`HP.example.com`

`media.example.com`

As, we have set the `domain globally` and will cover all the sites. But, i dont want to set cookie for the last site i.e. `media.example.com`

I have tried to set a domain as a `site URL` but it is not working as all the sites must share the `cookies` except the last one.

**Expected**

I don't want a `cookie` to be shared with `media.example.com` and shared with the other sites.

Comment: Have you tried to set coockie with explicit domain names? 
EX: Set-Cookie: name=value; domain= HP.example.com
EX: Set-Cookie: name=value; domain= articles.example.com

Also have a look at HOST-ONLY cookie

Comment: site specific domain cookie will have a problem if we have to share a cookie across the sites. i.e. a username from `login.example.com` to others site. As they have dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

To not set cookies for media.example.com I would do it like that:
If you set the cookies in an aspx.cs file:

```
string sHost = Request.Url.ToString();
if (!sHost.StartsWith("https://media.example.com"))
{
    //Write the code to set the cookies
}
```

If you set the cookies in a class file:

```
string sHost = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();
if (!sHost.StartsWith("https://media.example.com"))
{
   //Write the code to set the cookies
}
```

If you wouldn't use https then replace that with http.
I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Nope this will not work, as i want to set for domain and not for particular sites. Lets say i want to share a data within the sites this will not work.

Comment: If you set myCookie.Domain = .example.com then all the subdomains will get the cookie set and the dot infront of  example.com indicates that's global. As the if statement will not set the cookie for media.example.come I think it should work. I have done this on a project with 1,484 subdomains (didn't need to exclude a domain).

Comment: I dont have a code behind for `media.example.com`, it is a separate site for assets and which has only assets (images, JS . etc)

Comment: I guess I don't duplicate your problem fully. Here what I understand: You don't want to set cookies for media.example.com. You don't have a code behind file for media.example.com and therefore there are no cookies set. media.example.com hosts your resources only. I guess the other domains have links containing media.example.com for those resources. What concern do you have so that the global cookies bother you. I might miss something, but if you don't set cookies on media.example.com your visitor could get one only of they visit one of your other domains and then it would be valid, right?

Comment: it will be automatically set the cookie as domain is same.